# PhoneGap + jQuery Mobile: click on an <a> and smartphone shows phone call screen

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a PhoneGap+jQuery Mobile android index.html file.

```
    <div data-role="page" id="dashboard"> has a <ul><li> like this.
    <li>
      <a href="#enterInfo">정보 입력</a>
    </li>
```

when I click #enterInfo li, the page sometimes changes correctly to this page.

```
    <!-- page enterInfo -->
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="enterInfo">

<div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
    <a href="#dashboard" data-icon="delete">cancel</a>
    <h1>정보 입력</h1>
    <a href="#dashboard" data-icon="check" data-theme="b">save</a>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content" id="enterInfo" >  
  <p>
    <form method="post" class="dialog" id="enterInfoForm" action="http://wafflemaker.kr/flatlens/enterInfo.php" data-ajax="true">
    <fieldset>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
     <p id="juminP">
      <label for="jumin">주민등록번호</label>
      <input type="text" id="jumin1" name="jumin1" size="6" />-<input type="password" id="jumin2" name="jumin2" size="6" />
      <label for="age">연령</label>
     </p>
      <select name="age">
        <option value="20s" selected>20대</option>
        <option value="30s">30대</option>
        <option value="40s">40대</option>
        <option value="50s">50대</option>
        <option value="60s">60대</option>
      </select>
      <label for="as_dong">주소(지역구를 찾아줍니다)</label>
      <input type="text" id="as_dong" name="as_dong" value=""/>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="as_search" name="as_search" value="검색">    
    <!--
    <a href="index.html" rel="external" data=role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data=theme="a" 
    onclick="searchAddress(document.getElementById('as_dong').value);">검색</a>
    -->
    <a class="button" type="submit" id="enterInfoFormSubmit" name="submit" href="#">전송</a>
  </fieldset>
  </form>
</p>
<div id="as_show"></div>

    검색어 -> 부산광역시 : 부산광역시를 가지는 주소를 표시<br>
    검색어 -> 거제3동 : 거제3동을 가지는 주소를 표시
</div><!-- /content -->
```

But after 4-5 repetition of clicking on li -> cancel, the screen changes to phone call screen, with numbers 1270-50193.

What the bug. Can you please help it out?

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet the ids are duplicated:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="enterInfo">
<div data-role="content" id="enterInfo" >
```